# Customizing groups height in Infragistics Gallery Tool

Tags: gallery, infragistics

I'm using Infragistics NetAdvantage for Win Client 2010 Vol. 3.

I added a PopupGalleryTool to a ribbon: the tool's Preferred Size property is set to Large, and the gallery shows a list of 24x24 icons , grouped by category.

What I'm looking for is: how can I customize groups height? I noticed that when Preferred Size is set to Normal, groups are smaller. I would like to have a smaller height also with "Large" Preferred Size. Is it possible?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Are you talking about the category groups in the PopupGalleryTool's drop down or the RibbonGroups? If you are referring to RibbonGroups, do you want to make the whole group have a smaller height, or just the PopupGalleryTool instance within the group? If you post screenshots of the differences in height to which you are referring, it would help.

Comment: Hi Mike, nice to hear from you again :) I can't post images, since my reputation is too low... Anyway, I'm talking about category groups in PopupGalleryTool. Is there any way to customize groups' height?

Comment: [sample image] (http://static.inky.ws/image/361/image.jpg)

Comment: I added the image to the post. It will show up when it is peer reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in heights actually seems like a bug. You should probably submit it to Infragistics support: http://www.infragistics.com/support/submitrequest.aspx

Currently, the only way to control the height of the group header is to change the font size. This can be done by setting the PopupGalleryTool.GroupSettings.HeaderAppearance.FontData.SizeInPoints to a custom value.

Comment: But, in this way, text would become too smaller... Ok, we'll submit a bug request. Thank you.